# KeyError: 'Label' error in my image classification project in google colab

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, classification, google-colaboratory

I am dealing with a project that detects eczema and acne on the skin. I am working in Colab. I did not encounter such a problem when I ran the codes alone with my acne dataset, but when I work with acne and eczema together, I get the error I will mention below.My dataset contains separate acne and eczema folders within train and test folders.   Previously I did the assignment for both as I showed below the error message.

```
batch_size = 8
train_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=final_df,
    x_col="Image",
    y_col="Label",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",#sparse
    subset='training',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
valid_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=final_df,
    x_col="Image",
    y_col="Label",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical", #sparse
    subset='validation',
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42 
)
test_generator = test_data_gen.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe=final_test_df,
    x_col="Image",
    y_col="Label",
    target_size=(256, 256),
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode='categorical',
    shuffle=False,
)
```

These are my error codes I get the following error:

````
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801             try:
-> 3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:

7 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Label'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'Label'```
````

```
final_test_df = pd.DataFrame()
eczema_test_df = pd.DataFrame()
eczema_test_df['Image'] =  [eczema_test_path+'/'+img for img in eczema_test_files]
eczema_test_df['Label'] = "eczema"
```